# Jinja2 indentation on every line of multiline substitute

Tags: jinja2

Say I have a template:

```
<tag>
    {{ x }}
</tag>
```

and I set x equal to:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I get:

```
<tag>
    1
2
3
4
5
</tag>
```

How should I change the template to get:

```
<tag>
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
</tag>
```

?

Thank you.

Comment: try {{ x | indent(4)}}

Comment: to include the first line: indent(4, true) https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#indent